# Schema/Database Created in Python Code is not appearing in MySQL Workbench / MySQL Server

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to create the schema/database in python code and am able to create the tables , insert the data into that but when i check in MySQL work bench , the created database in Python is not appearing.

my work space details :

Installed mysql conector: pip install mysql-connector-python

Python Version : 3.8

MySql Version 8.0

here is the code i have written in python

code snippet :

```
import mysql.connector
mydb=mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",user="root",passwd="mysql")
mycursor=mydb.cursor()
mycursor.execute("create database databaseforpython4")
```

And also able to access the schema created in Python only but not able to create the schema created in MySQL

Comment: I have two instances of MySQL in my system one with port number 3306 and another with port number 3307. I was not using the 3306 instance as it is old version and when i tried to connect the MySQL from Python , it was using the port 3306 by default but i was looking in 3307 instance. So, in python i have port number externally then i am able to see the schema created.

Answer (score 0):

Use the command [USE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/use.html) after the create databse and there you can add a new table like the example

```
 import mysql.connector
 mydb=mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",user="root",passwd="mysql",     database="formtest")
 mycursor=mydb.cursor()
 mycursor.execute("create database databaseforpython4")
 mycursor.execute("use databaseforpython4")
 mycursor.execute("CREATE TABLE `a` ( `a_col1` varchar(40) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci DEFAULT NULL, `a_col2` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL, KEY `testindex2` (`a_col2`)) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;")
```

Workbench shiow after running the code the new database and the new table.

Tested with VS Code and Python 3.8.2

Comment: Thanks for writing out but it is not working...i tried this before posting

Comment: make a try catch and see what error you get, as i wrote the same code works fine, because the user has the privilege for that . but you make no error handling at all

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify on which port you are working with in MySQL, for example if you are using the default port you need to change your code to:

```
db = mysql.connector.connect(
     host="localhost",
     user="root",
     passwd="mysql",
     database="testdatabase",
     port="3306")
```